# How to match functions as parameters with RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following JavaScript RegEx to match functions prefixed by `theme-`.

`/(theme-([\w-]+))(?:\s*\(\s*)([^)]+?)(?:\s*\))/gm`

However, I also need to match other functions as parameters, like `theme-foo(param1, theme-bar(arg1)), param3)`, but this RegEx isn't working because it assumes that the closing parentheses of the function being called in a parameter is the closing parentheses of the main function.

[RegEx Example with the issue](https://regex101.com/r/Ts3ajP/3)

How can I do this?

Comment: Write an actual parser for the target grammar.

Comment: Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns

Answer (score 0):

How about follow:

```js
let s = `theme-foo(param1, theme-bar(arg1), param3)`;
let regex = /([\w-]+(\(\w+\))?)/g;
let result = [];
s.replace(regex,function(match,param){
    result.push(param);
});
console.log(result);
```